# How to split a String array into separate int and String arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have this code that I am trying to sort. Therefore, I want to split my array into one called ages, and the other called names. Here is what I have so far:

```
    String na = "Jones 14 \nAbrams 15 \nSmith 19 \nJones 9\nAlexander 22\nSmith 20\nSmith 17\nTippurt 42\nJones 2\nHerkman 12\nJones 11";
    String text[] = na.split("\\s+");
```

So far, this only splits the array at whitespace. I want my output to have all the numbers in ages[], and all the words in names[].

Comment: Is that the exact format of the string of data? If it is, split according to whitespace, loop through array, place even indices into `name` array, odd indices into `age` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by the newline character first.

```
String lines = na.split("\n");
```

When looping through `lines`, split each line by whitespace, `\\s+`, to split each field on the current line.

```
for (String line : lines)
{
   String[] text = line.split("\\s+");
   // other processing
}
```

Then you can access the individual values and assign them to arrays or whatever you'd like.  Your idea of storing 2 arrays would work fine, but I would create an array or a `List` of `Person` objects that are defined to hold your fields such as name and age.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    String names[] = na.split("\\s*\\d+\\s*");
    String ages[] = na.split("\\s*\\D+\\s*");
```

You should fine tune it a bit but the idea should be OK.